# Communicating with USB bluetooth dongle from FTDI vinculum 2 USB host controller

Tags: bluetooth, usb

I have been asked to figure out how to achieve bluetooth communication through an off-the-shelf dongle (in this case a dongle utilizing the Broadcom BCM2045 chip) using the FTDI Vinculum 2 (VNC2) USB controller. I have custom firmware written for the VNC2 to communicate with a generic USB device with the VNC2 acting as the host, and I can successfully read the VID and PID from the dongle as well as the USB device class, subclass, and protocol. I can also send data to the dongle using the bulk data endpoint and I believe the device is receiving though I have no way to tell at the moment.

So I believe I can communicate with the dongle, the problem is I have no idea WHAT to communicate to it in order to set it up in discoverable mode or to pair it with another discoverable device, nor how to actually transmit data through the wireless link once it is paired. I don't even know if there exists a standard communication protocol for this type of thing or if every device will be different. I have a vague understanding of the bluetooth protocol stack and it is my understanding that I won't be required to fully understand that as it should be implemented in the dongle on one end and in the android smartphone that we hope to connect to on the other end. Like I said, I can currently send data to the bulk endpoint, is it true that this endpoint is only for data transfer over the wireless link and I will need to connect to a different endpoint in order to send setup/configuration messages to the dongle?

In short, I need to know what data to send over the USB bus to control any generic bluetooth dongle if possible or at least one specific bluetooth dongle. I have a USB port sniffer but the complexity of the output while using the dongle to communicate is staggering and I doubt I'll ever figure it out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth dongles communicate with host software stack using HCI (host control interface), which is defined in the Bluetooth spec.  For reference, you can look at source code for the open source BlueZ stack (standard linux stack).  You could run BlueZ on linux talking to your USB dongle, and use [hcidump](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/hcidump8.html) to capture actual packets going across HCI.  You can also check out hcitool and hciconfig for performing specific actions.

Comment: Oh I see, so I will have to implement the HCI layer of the stack... I'll probably also have to implement all higher layers then as well correct (or at least the ones we need)?

Do you think I'll have to implement L2CAP, SDP, and RFCOMM myself then? What layers are implemented on the dongle?

Thank you for your response it is already very helpful!

Comment: The dongle supports everything below HCI (LMP - link management protocol, MAC layer, physical layer).  What you need to implement really depends on what you want to do.  To talk to other standard stacks/devices, then yes that would include at least a subset of L2CAP.  The other profiles you need depend on your application.